# Vector2.Distance on different resolutions

Tags: unity, resolution

```
firstTouchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

endTouchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

                        //the height of the background(previously scaled to fit the screen) / 10
minSlidedDistance = (int)(SpriteRend.bounds.size.y / 10);

if (Vector2.Distance(firstTouchPos, endTouchPos) > minSlidedDistance)
{
  //do smth
}
```

This way I check if the player has slided into any direction with a slided distance longer than minSlidedDistance. It works perfectly for different size devices.

**Is unity going to make the calculations itself if I simply write minSlidedDistance = 100? I.e. is it still going to work same way on all devices?**

P.S. this is not the full code, there are many other IF checks, like the ones for assigning the value to firstTouchPos & endTouchPos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unity does make the calculations itself.

Test case: Game Window -> select different resolutions and run the following code:

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            firstTouchPos = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            endTouchPos = Input.mousePosition;
            Debug.Log(Vector2.Distance(firstTouchPos, endTouchPos));
        }
    }
```